# TypeError: printName1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

So I have this very simple thing I wrote and it's killing me trying to figure out why it won't work. All it does it print a statement when you click.

So for the first example I had a button and assigned the function `printName1` directly to it, which worked perfectly fine.

Then the next thing was to bind it using the `.bind()` function. So in this case we just have a frame that prints out certain things based on which button you press. But unfortunately whenever I use bind, it throws the error show above. References `tkinter\__init__.py` for the error, so it's not something directly in my code but maybe it needs to be done differently? Thanks guys.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def printName1():
    print('Jack')

def printName2():
    print('John')

def printName3():
    print('Jill')

frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=250)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", printName1)
frame.bind("<Button-2>", printName2)
frame.bind("<Button-3>", printName3)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: The error is confusing because it made it seem like there was an extra argument when there should be 0. But actually I needed to add an argument to the functions and that was event. so it should be def printName1(event) and so on. Just figured I would let you guys know what worked for me in case anyone stumbles upon this.

Answer (score 5):

If you refer to the [documentation regarding tkinter events and bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm), you will see that when an event is triggered, the associated event object will be passed as the first (and only) argument to the bounded function (being `printName1` and friends in your case).

So what you need to do is to modify those `printName*` functions to accept the event argument.

```
def printName1(event):
    print('Jack')
```

Then what you desired to achieve should work.

Naturally, you could make the `event` argument optional as @TigerhawkT3 suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Events, such as from the keyboard/mouse, are all sent to the application with information about the event: which key was it, where was the mouse when you clicked, that sort of thing. This means that any callback bound to such an event needs to take an argument. If you want to also bind it to a Tkinter `Button`, which doesn't take an event, you can handle that as well. Just define your functions with a default argument:

```
def printName1(event=None):
    ...
```

Comment: not just keyboard and mouse events, but all events.

Comment: I didn't think of other input devices, like joysticks. I suppose it's any user input other than, say, `Button` activations?

Comment: There are virtual events such as `<<ListboxSelect>>`, as well as low level events like `<Configure>`, `<Visibility>` and others.

Comment: Ah yes, very true. Any such callback will need a parameter for the event.